# Can't load Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

When I start Visual Studio 2013 and click on SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual Studio 2013, I get this error:

The 'Microsoft SQL Server data tools' package did not load correctly. The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file C:\User[user Name]\App data\Roaming\Microsoft\visual studio\12.0\Activitylog.xml'.

Please help me.
I also get two more following errors:
1st) HRESULT E_Fail has been returned from a call to a COM component.
2nd) the system cannot find the file specified (Exception from HRESULT: 0*80070002)
and the Log files errors:
(sory the formatting is not good)

ERROR# 266 Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information. C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\SQLDB\VSIX\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.SQLPDWExtensions.dll

ERROR#  267  Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.RegSvrEnum, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\SQLDB\VSIX\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.SQLPDWExtensions.dll